I get the error "The specified token cannot be used with this resource server" when app is deployed, but not in local dev environment
Some quick context on the system I am developing before getting into the problem. I have an Single Sign On (SSO) system where the Identity Provider (IDP) has an API endpoint for user management. There is an Admin Client application which acts as a front end for user management. The user can log in and use the Admin Client to view, add, edit and delete users.
In this system, authorisation code flow is used to log in and access the client and its actions. The controllers in the Admin Client will send requests to the API endpoint of the IDP when the user performs user administration actions. For example, something as simple as loading the homepage of the Admin Client, the homepage controller calls a method that makes a request to the IDP's API endpoint which will return a JSON file that can be passed back to the homepage to display in a table on the front end.
The homepage controller in the Admin Client is already protected by a policy that checks the user's authentication and role before allowing them to use it, therefore the request that the Admin Client makes to the IDP's API endpoint is protected using the client credentials flow.
OpenIddict is used in this system for authentication and authorisation.
This all works fine in a local development environment. However, we are now trying to deploy this system onto a live server in order to test/demo it and we are getting an error in the request made by the Admin Client to the IDP's API endpoint. When the app is deployed, the user is able to log into the Admin Client fine, however loading the home page does not work because the request to the IDP API endpoint returns a 401 unauthorized response.
Looking into the logs for this, it seems the problem is to do with the audience value of the token:
The authentication demand was rejected because the token had no valid audience.
The contents of the token generated from the live system looked like this (after being decoded via jwt.io):
{
  "iss": "https://company.solutions/SSO_IDP",
  "exp": 1729258266,
  "iat": 1729254666,
  "aud": "https://company.solutions/SSO_IDP",
  "jti": "2a5427c7-b155-496d-8df8-0191649ad580",
  "sub": "adminclient",
  "name": "adminclient",
  "oi_prst": "adminclient",
  "client_id": "adminclient",
  "oi_tkn_id": "f0ae2cd7-aa03-4d3a-89ea-fbe2decf5b24"
}

And the contents of the token generated from the local system looks like this:
{
  "iss": "https://localhost:7007/",
  "exp": 1729262935,
  "iat": 1729259335,
  "aud": "https://localhost:7007/",
  "jti": "65f8902a-99fb-4f1b-84e4-ef1422fa9b7c",
  "sub": "adminclient",
  "name": "adminclient",
  "oi_prst": "adminclient",
  "client_id": "adminclient",
  "oi_tkn_id": "52352ecf-d942-4e13-fb69-5e15d7ccd956"
}

The only difference in the audience being that our live system is being run on a subpage (hence the /SSO_IDP), and also the localhost issuer and audience have a "/" at the end when the live one does not (this has caused problems with connecting the IDP to the Admin Client previously).
The way it gets the issuer URL and audience for this exchange is through a value set in appsettings.json. This value is then used in places such as setting the issuer of the client when registering it:
options.AddRegistration(new OpenIddictClientRegistration
{
    ClientId = clientDetails.GetSection("ClientId").Value?.ToString(),
    ClientSecret = clientDetails.GetSection("ClientSecret").Value?.ToString(),
    Issuer = new Uri(clientDetails.GetSection("IssuerUrl").Value?.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute),

    // Other options go here...
});

And when setting the audience in the IDP:
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.AddAudiences(new Uri(configuration["AllowedDomains:IssuerUrl"]).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/");
    });

As well as setting the audience of the token in the exchange endpoint of the IDP.
My questions are:

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here, and why the audience being sent in the live app is not valid when it works in the local environment?

Is there a better way of setting these values? Or more so, what is the recommended way of doing it?

Is there a better way of testing/investigating this going forward, so I can better tackle the issue?


I apologise for the long post, but I appreciate any help offered. Thank you in advance.

This is a common problem. I don't know about Keycloak specifically, but in some similar systems, the issuer value depends on the application's origin when making the authentication request.
I am sure you can hardcode the issuer to be static somehow. In IdentityServer, which I used, I had to hardcode the issuer to get it to work.
The core issue is that, depending on how you deployed it, the issue is one value when the user is making the authentication request but a different value when the client application exchanges the authorization code for the actual tokens.
See https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/set-iss-in-jwt-to-custom-value-hardcoded-okay/21687
